# How no Contact forces on objects with stacked on top of each other

Tags: free-fall, contact-mechanics

How can there be no contact force between two bodies stack one top of another during freefall if they are in contact?ho

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful in presenting a question like that to eliminate all ambiguities.

If you stack two bodies one on top of the other on the ground, then there will be a contact force owing to the weight of the upper body being resisted by the lower one.

If you place the two bodies next to each other in freefall in a vacuum, the lower body will no longer resist the weight of the upper body, as they are both accelerating at the same rate.

There may be other forces acting between the bodies if they are in very close contact, such as electrostatic forces.

You must also be clear about how you bring the two bodies together during freefall, as that might determine whether there are any transient forces between them if the bodies are bumped together in some way.

If the bodies are not in a vacuum, then the lower body will meet air resistance which will cause it to act as a brake on the acceleration of the upper body, thus resulting in a contact force.

So you see, you must clarify the circumstances that apply to your question if you want a definitive answer.

Comment: OKAY SO IF  LETS CONSIDER TWO BODIES ONE TOP OF THE ANOTHER IN FREE FALL (NO AIR DRAG). IF THERE NO CONTACT FORCES SO NO FRICTION SO HOW DO THEY REMAIN IN CONTACT. DOES THEIR INTERMOLECULAR DISTANCE CHANGES WHEN THEY ON EARTH AT REST. DO IT INCREASE. WHAT HOLDS THEM TOGETHER

Comment: They remain in contact because there is nothing pulling them apart. If two objects are positioned a certain distance from each other and are uniformly accelerated they will remain the same distance apart. That is true even if the distance is zero.

Comment: does the intermolecular distance changes when there was a normal reaction force to when they are in free fall (ignore are drag) and there is no contact force

Comment: If they were initially stacked on a trapdoor say, which was resisting their weight, before being dropped in freefall, then while on the trapdoor each body would be compressed slightly in a vertical direction. Once the trapdoor is opened, that compression would relax.

Comment: why do then people start float upwards during free fall like in a lift freely falling why can they just stand still

Comment: If you were in a lift that suddenly dropped in freefall, the muscles in your feet and legs that had been supporting the weight of your torso would momentarily continue to exert forces before they relaxed in the absence of weight. That would be enough to make you rise relative to the floor of the lift towards the ceiling. You would find it quite difficult to stand weightless on the floor, as your muscles would not be used to it.

Comment: If a steel ball or any object is placed on trampoline, the trampoline would would stretch inward. Now at this position if the both of them are in released in a free fall ,ignoring air drag with initial velocity zero, ignoring air drag, will the compression relax, will it remain the same and will there be any change in distance between the steel ball and the rubber of the trampoline. Since during free fall there are no normal forces are play, what will happen to the trampoline. Will it provide an upward acceleration to the ball or not?

Comment: Yes, the trampoline was only stretched because of the weight of the ball, so it will relax in freefall. It is exactly the same as if the person was standing on a set of scales in a stationary lift- springs in the scales compress to move a pointer to show the weight of the person. If the lift goes into freefall, the springs will relax by pushing the person upwards and the scales will show no weight. Quite how that happens exactly might depend on how the springs are damped, etc etc.